# Dagger class cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

Hello I'm new to `Dagger` and I have crated a simple project to learn more about it. I have a class `PermissionManager` that has activity as constructor parameter

```
  class PermissionManager(activity: MainActivity) {

  }
```

and my `MainFragment` has a dependency on it. So I created `BindingModule`

```
@Module
interface BindingModule {

    @DaggerScope(MainActivity::class)
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    fun provideMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFragmentModule::class])
    fun provideMainFragment(): MainFragment
}
```

Here's my `MainActivityModule` that provides `PermissionManager`

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule private constructor() {

    @Module
    companion object {
        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun providePermissionManager(activity: MainActivity): PermissionManager = PermissionManager(activity)
    }
}
```

and here's my `MainFragmentModule` that has to use `PermissionManager` that was created in my `MainActivityModule`

```
@Module
abstract class MainFragmentModule private constructor() {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(MyTestViewModel::class)
        fun provideModelFactory(
            permissionManager: PermissionManager
        ): ViewModel = MyTestViewModel(permissionManager)
    }
}
```

and here's what I get

```
com\nav\component\di\AppComponent.java:12: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.nav.component.utils.PermissionManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.nav.component.MyTestDaggerApp>
```

So first of all I don't understand why I can't use dependency that was created for `activity` in my `fragment`? Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:

Here's how Binding Module is used

```
@AppScope
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        BindingModule::class,
        NetworkingModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyTestDaggerApp> {

    /**
     * AppComponent Builder interface. All implementation part is handled by a dagger compiler.
     */
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<MyTestDaggerApp>
}
```

Comment: Please show how `BindingModule` is being used.

Comment: I think the reason of this problem is trying to inject your activity into the PermissionManager

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu why are you thinking so? I think that somehow `MainFragmentModule` doesn't see the objects that are created in `MainActivityModule`

Comment: can you add @Inject constructor into the PermissionManager and then try to compile

Comment: I've added, same issue :/

Comment: @David can you share your project on github?

Comment: @David can you also share which tutorial you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragment a subcomponent of `BindingModule` to get bindings from it. Don't forget to make `MainActivity` implement `HasAndroidInjector` (if it doesn’t already).

```
@Module
interface BindingModule {

    @DaggerScope(MainActivity::class)
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class, MainFragmentBindingModule::class])
    fun provideMainActivity(): MainActivity
}

@Module
interface MainFragmentBindingModule {

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFragmentModule::class])
    fun provideMainFragment(): MainFragment
}
```